# What's the difference between "rapid" and non-rapid Feisol tripods?

Tags: tripod

Currently, I've set my eyes on the Feisol 3442 tripod. But can someone tell me what the difference between the rapid and non-rapid is? The price difference of the two where I live is $100, and I want to know for sure whether I need that feature or not.

Comment: You can still order the non-rapid ones from Feisol.

Answer (score 3):

The Rapid series has redesigned locks and non-rotating leg segments, which make them faster to set up, tear down and adjust. If you can lay your hands on one of the "classics", you won't be at all disappointed, but they've been discontinued (which probably explains the much lower price).